# Simulate mysql utf8_general_ci collaction

Tags: javascript, mysql, string, comparison, collation

I'm trying to integrate a javascript application with a third party API that creates names in a database. My issue is that third party application uses utf8_general_ci collation for determining the uniqueness of the names and in my application I need to dynamically decide if the name that I'm going to send already exists in their database, as to prevent a duplicate name error. Basically the flow goes:

1. My application takes user input for a name: "somename"
2. My application does a search request to the third party API for "somename", which returns:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Somënamë"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "somename somesecondname"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "somename someothername"
  }
]
```

3. My application needs to determine if I should create a new record "somename" or reuse one of the results

In this case my application needs to figure out that "somename" and "Somënamë" are equal in a utf8_general_ci comparison and the record with id=1 should be used, instead of trying to create a new record (which will result in a duplicate name)

Basically I need to perform the same comparison of string as the third party database

One option I've tried is literally using a mysql instance to check that like

```
SELECT IF(_utf8:string1 COLLATE utf8_general_ci = _utf8:string2 COLLATE utf8_general_ci, "true", "false") as equals;
```

but that is too resource intensive for my case, where we might have thousands of results..

Is there a way to simulate this collation check in javascript at least semi-accurately, without having to use a database on my side?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you are working too hard.

If the column and the connection are declared to be `COLLATION utf8_general_ci`, then  `Somënamë` = `somename` since the `_ci` means case folding and accent stripping.

Have the column `UNIQUE`.  Instead of doing the `SELECT`, just check for a dup key error on the `INSERT`.

Comment: Hey, and thank you for your reply!

In my case the `UNIQUE` column is in the third party database I'm creating/updating/deleting records at, and I need to check if something would match in that collation, before I send my CREATE request. Basically I'm first doing a loose search request to the database and I need in my application to check if one of the search results would match what I want to create in utf8_general_ci, before I actually send the request. E.g. I need to perform that utf8_general_ci in my javascript application on a list of items.

Comment: Right now as a solution, I'm just doing the case folding and accent stripping of all my strings in javascript and comparing that way, but I wonder if I need to do anything else to match what the collation check SQL would do?

Comment: @SimeonBorisov - If the collations don't match, the index is not used.  It does not matter if you have already done case folding and accent stripping; it will be slow.